# GAS - "We're sorry, a server error occurred" when using "debug" option - even after waiting

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script

I have created a "library" with a project name of GAS, in a spreadsheet named GAS_library.
The library project has two versions defined.

I have created another project in the same spreadsheet file called GAS_testing.

In the project "GAS_testing" I have two files:
  "test_get_set.gs" and "GAS_stubs".

In the file "test_get_set.gs" I have created a routine to test some of the
routines in the "GAS" project.

In the file "GAS_stubs" I have a set of "stub" routines.
Their purpose is provide a local definition of the GAS library functions
with out have to code the "GAS" qualifier in every call in the application.
All that the "stub" routine does is call the same function with the leading "GAS." qualifier.

I have obtained the project property for the "GAS" project, and defined it in
the "GAS_testing" project with the current version (2); I have the "development mode"
set to "yes".

When I run (without debug) the "test_get_set" function, execution proceeds to the
end, but it returns at least one wrong value. So to debug it, I pressed the little "bug" icon in the editor.

Whenever I do this I always receive the error message "We're sorry, a server error has occurred - wait and try again".  It does not seem to matter how long I wait.

The call "trace-back" stack indicates:
       gas_var_alert[19]
       gas_var_msg[27]
       GAS_stubs: gas_var_msg[43]
       test_get_set: test_get_set[6].

I noticed in the spreadsheet "tab" that the Browser.msgBox display is showing with the
text that was passed when/or just before the error occurred. Pressing the "OK" button
in the message box does not solve the problem.

The only function of the GAS.gas_var_alert routine is to issue the Browser.msgBox command
with the passed input parameter. 
The function of the GAS.gas_var_msg routine is to add some formatting text around the
its input parameter and pass it to the gas_var_alert function.

Any idea of why the debugger/server is failing? I am knew to this environment.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Browser.msgBox()` works differently than other function, and you may be experiencing an error like the one listed in [Issue 1267](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1267).

Answer (score 0):

After doing additional testing and investigation I found out that:

When the first call to google services, in a debug mode execution (no break points), occurs 
in a library routine, you receive the warning message (in red):
"We're sorry a sever error occurred. Please wait and try again" (dismiss).

After further testing I found that
    1) even with the error reported the track back is correct.
    2) this error message can be ignored (must be dismissed) and the
       script will continue to execute in the debug mode.
       It returns to the calling routine that issues its
       own call to google services and the debug process halts
       at that point. 
    3) If you do not set break points then the debug service will automatically
       break at each google service call.